# AWTPermission Exception while implementing Automatic update desktop application using java web start

Tags: windows, exception, desktop-application, java-web-start

I am working in a Desktop application that provides Online Backup of data. In my application  i am trying to implement automatic software update feature. For this i am using java web start. I have done the following process for using java web start.

1> created jar with all resources.
2> created jnlp file as :

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <jnlp spec="1.0+" 
               codebase="http://cmswebusa.com/kapil"
              href="PixelVaultJNLP.jnlp">
                <information>
                        <title>PixelVault</title>
                          <vendor>globussoft</vendor>
                           </information>
                        <resources>
                     <!-- Application Resources -->       
                          <jar href="PixelVault.jar" main="true" />

                     </resources>
                   <application-desc
                   name="PixelVault"
                   main-class="com.pixelvault.systemtray.SysTray">
                   </application-desc>
                   <update check="background"/>
                </jnlp>
```

where PixelVault.jar is jar of the application which is on http server location.

while i am trying to download my application using command prompt run option by typing :
javaws , i am getting AWT Permission Exception as:

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied "java.awt.AWTPermission"

it says "java.awt.AWTPermissionException""accessSystemTray". I am not getting how can i allow my application to use system tray.

Please guide to make changes in jnlp file or making any other change in my application.

I thanks to your all valuable suggestions that will help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of that error:

- The JNLP will need to declare all-permissions within a security element.
- The code will need to be digitally signed.

Note that the JNLP file has elements out of the correct order.  Use [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) to check the validity of the file as well as other aspects of the launch.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question but i am having another problem with digital signature. i am following the process maintioned by http://wiki.plexinfo.net/index.php?title=How_to_sign_JAR_files and in the step 5> sign the JAR file with the test certificate i am getting error jarsigner: unable to open jar file: http://cmswebusa.com/kapil/PixelVault.jar. Is there any way to check what can be the reason for this error. Please guide me for this.

Comment: The message suggests that you are attempting to sign a Jar file that is already on the net.  To be successful, the Jar must be on the local file system.  Sign it there, then upload it.